# Программа выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'k' is not defined. Суть программы описана в комментариях, никак не могу понять почему не работает. Спасибо!

Tags: python

```
#Что больше сумма нечетных чисел от 1 до 199 или сумма четных 2 до 198?
print('Привет! Если ты хочешь узнать, что больше: сумма нечетных чисел от 1 до 199 или сумма четных от 2 до 198, то скажи "Да"')

def vv():
    k=input()
    
vv()

if k == 'Да':
    print('Тогда держи ответ')
elif k == 'Нет':
    print('Хорошо! Тогда не буду отвлекать тебя!')
    exit()
else:
    print('Какой-то некорректный ответ. Давай еще разок!!')
    vv()

s = 0
i = 1
 
while i <= 199:
    if i % 2 != 0:
        s += i
    i += 1
 
print('Сумма нечетных чисел от 1 до 199 равна ',s)

a = 0
b = 2
 
while b <= 198:
    if b % 2 == 0:
        a += i
    b += 1
 
print('Сумма четных чисел от 2 до 198 равна ',a)
```

Comment: Думаю тебе стоит почитать про локальные и глобальные переменные, что бы решить твою ситуацию(ответить на твой вопрос) тебе необходимо внутри функции `def vv():` добавить последней строчку `return k` а в строчках где происходит вызов функции `vv()` написать `k=vv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в **области видимости переменных**. Если ты создаешь переменную в функции то вне функции ты не сможешь к ней обратиться т.к. она пропадет из видимости.
Решений есть несколько:

1. Можно сделать переменную k глобальной и тогда к ней можно будет обращаться отовсюду. (Для данной ситуации это явно не оптимально решение, но про него важно знать)
2. Переписать функцию, что бы она возвращала значение, а уже в программе принимать его в переменную.

Но это лишь уберет ошибку NameError, но что более важно логика программы явно не придусматривает повторного ввода, т.к. даже когда повторно вызывается функция vv, то мы не проверяем значение k, а переходим к подсчету.
Что бы решить все проблемы можно использовать цикл while:

```
k = input()
while not (k == 'Да' or k == 'Нет'): #будет работать пока не скажем Да или Нет
    print('Какой-то некорректный ответ. Давай еще разок!!')
    k = input()

if k == 'Да':
    print('Тогда держи ответ')
else:
    print('Хорошо! Тогда не буду отвлекать тебя!')
    exit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, Руслан! Это очень полезный ответ. Я понял сразу несколько моментов!!!

Answer (score 0):

Потому что k - локальная переменная, существующая только внутри функции vv. Не выноси ввод внутрь функции/используй global (не советую)/используй return